# Change values while iterating

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go

Let's suppose I have these types:

```
type Attribute struct {
    Key, Val string
}
type Node struct {
    Attr []Attribute
}
```

and that I want to iterate on my node's attributes to change them.

I would have loved to be able to do:

```
for _, attr := range n.Attr {
    if attr.Key == "href" {
        attr.Val = "something"
    }
}
```

but as `attr` isn't a pointer, this wouldn't work and I have to do:

```
for i, attr := range n.Attr {
    if attr.Key == "href" {
        n.Attr[i].Val = "something"
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler or faster way? Is it possible to directly get pointers from `range`?

Obviously I don't want to change the structures just for the iteration and more verbose solutions are no solutions.

Comment: So you want some kind of `Array.prototype.forEach` in JavaScript?

Comment: That's an interesting idea and that could have been a solution but calling a function which would in turn call a function at each iteration looks heavy and wrong in a server side language. And the lacks of generics would make this feel even heavier.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's that heavy. Calling a function or two is very cheap, this is usually what compilers optimize the most. I'd try it and benchmark it to see if its fits the bill.

Comment: As Go lacks generics, I'm afraid the function passed to `forEach` would necessarily start with a type assertion. That's not really better than `attr := &n.Attr[i]`.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

No, the abbreviation you want is not possible.

The reason for this is that `range` copies the values from the slice you're iterating over.
The [specification about range](http://golang.org/ref/spec#RangeClause) says:

> ```
> Range expression                          1st value             2nd value (if 2nd variable is present)
> array or slice  a   [n]E, *[n]E, or []E   index    i  int       a[i]       E
> ```

So, range uses `a[i]` as its second value for arrays/slices, which effectively means that the
value is copied, making the original value untouchable.

This behavior is demonstrated by the [following code](http://play.golang.org/p/fTLS5Y69Mk):

```
x := make([]int, 3)

x[0], x[1], x[2] = 1, 2, 3

for i, val := range x {
    println(&x[i], "vs.", &val)
}
```

The code prints you completely different memory locations for the value from range and the actual 
value  in the slice:

```
0xf84000f010 vs. 0x7f095ed0bf68
0xf84000f014 vs. 0x7f095ed0bf68
0xf84000f018 vs. 0x7f095ed0bf68
```

So the only thing you can do is to either use pointers or the index, as already proposed by jnml and peterSO.

Comment: One way to think of this is that assigning a value causes a copy.  If you saw val := x[1], it would be completely unsurprising that val was a copy of x[1].  Rather than thinking of the range as doing something special, remember that each iteration of a range begins by assigning the index and value variables, and that it is that assignment rather than the range that causes the copy.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a little bit confuse here. If the 2nd value of for loop is a[i],
then what is the different between the ```a[i]``` from the for loop and the ```a[i]``` as we write? It looks like the same thing but it isn't, right?

Comment: @TiếnNguyễnHoàng `range` returns `a[i]` as its second return value. This operation, `val = a[i]`, as done by `range` creates a copy of the value so any write operation to `val` is applied to a copy.

Answer (score 50):

You seem to be asking for something equivalent to this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Attribute struct {
    Key, Val string
}
type Node struct {
    Attr []Attribute
}

func main() {

    n := Node{
        []Attribute{
            {"key", "value"},
            {"href", "http://www.google.com"},
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(n)

    for i := 0; i < len(n.Attr); i++ {
        attr := &n.Attr[i]
        if attr.Key == "href" {
            attr.Val = "something"
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

Output:

```
{[{key value} {href http://www.google.com}]}
{[{key value} {href something}]}
```

This avoids creating a--possibly large--copy of type `Attribute` values, at the expense of slice bounds checks. In your example, type `Attribute` is relatively small, two `string` slice references: 2 * 3 * 8 = 48 bytes on a 64-bit architecture machine.

You could also simply write:

```
for i := 0; i < len(n.Attr); i++ {
    if n.Attr[i].Key == "href" {
        n.Attr[i].Val = "something"
    }
}
```

But, the way to get an equivalent result with a `range` clause, which creates a copy but minimizes slice bounds checks, is:

```
for i, attr := range n.Attr {
    if attr.Key == "href" {
        n.Attr[i].Val = "something"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a pity that `value := &someMap[key]` will not work if `someMap` is a `map`

Comment: peterSO in your first code snippet don't you have to deference attr to assign something to it? i.e. `*attr.Val = "something"`

Comment: worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 46):

I'd adapt your last suggestion and use the index-only version of range.

```
for i := range n.Attr {
    if n.Attr[i].Key == "href" {
        n.Attr[i].Val = "something"
    }
}
```

It seems simpler to me to refer to `n.Attr[i]` explicitly in both the line that tests `Key` and the line that sets `Val`, rather than using `attr` for one and `n.Attr[i]` for the other.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer. I think the key here (no pun intended) is you're working on n.Attr while inside the range.

Answer (score 15):

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Attribute struct {
        Key, Val string
}

type Node struct {
        Attr []*Attribute
}

func main() {
        n := Node{[]*Attribute{
                &Attribute{"foo", ""},
                &Attribute{"href", ""},
                &Attribute{"bar", ""},
        }}

        for _, attr := range n.Attr {
                if attr.Key == "href" {
                        attr.Val = "something"
                }
        }

        for _, v := range n.Attr {
                fmt.Printf("%#v\n", *v)
        }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/5ohohUiNrU)

---

Output

```
main.Attribute{Key:"foo", Val:""}
main.Attribute{Key:"href", Val:"something"}
main.Attribute{Key:"bar", Val:""}
```

---

Alternative approach:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Attribute struct {
        Key, Val string
}

type Node struct {
        Attr []Attribute
}

func main() {
        n := Node{[]Attribute{
            {"foo", ""},
            {"href", ""},
            {"bar", ""},
        }}

        for i := range n.Attr {
                attr := &n.Attr[i]
                if attr.Key == "href" {
                        attr.Val = "something"
                }
        }

        for _, v := range n.Attr {
                fmt.Printf("%#v\n", v)
        }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/7lx8I3Qixr)

---

Output:

```
main.Attribute{Key:"foo", Val:""}
main.Attribute{Key:"href", Val:"something"}
main.Attribute{Key:"bar", Val:""}
```

Comment: I thought it was obvious but I don't want to change the structures I get (they're from the `go.net/html` package)

Comment: @dystroy: The second approach above _doesn't_ change the types (the "structures") wrt the OP.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's not really bringing anything. I was expecting an idea that I could possibly have missed. I you feel confident that there is no simpler solution then that would be the answer.

Comment: @dystroy: It _does_ bring something, it _doesn't_ copy here and back the whole Attribute. And yes, I'm confident that taking the address of a slice element to avoid a double copy (r+w) update of the element is the optimal solution.