# Call struct method in range loop

Tags: for-loop, go, range

example code (edited code snippet): http://play.golang.org/p/eZV4WL-4N_

Why is it that

```
for x, _ := range body.Personality {
    body.Personality[x].Mutate()
}
```

successfully mutates the structs' contents, but

```
for _, pf := range body.Personality{
    pf.Mutate()
}
```

does not? 
Is it that range creates new instances of each item it iterates over? because the struct does in fact mutate but it doesn't persist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change values while iterating in golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945030/change-values-while-iterating-in-golang)

Comment: Wasn't really sure where the underlying problem was, so I wasn't fully sure as to what I should've been searching for, that was one of my thoughts though, thanks.

Comment: Most of the time staring hard at the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) is enough (eventually the answer will jump you in the face). But I have to admit, this one is a bit tricky. I've updated my answer once again to quote the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range` keyword copies the results of the array, thus making it impossible to alter the
contents using the value of range. You have to use the index or a slice of pointers instead of values 
if you want to alter the original array/slice.

This behaviour is covered by the spec as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952415/1643939). The crux is that an assignment line
`x := a[i]` copies the value `a[i]` to `x` as it is no pointer. Since `range` is defined to use 
`a[i]`, the values are copied.

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop is roughly equivalent to:

```
for x := range body.Personality {
    pf := body.Personality[x]
    pf.Mutate()
}
```

Since `body.Personality` is an array of structs, the assignment to `pf` makes a copy of the struct, and that is what we call `Mutate()` on.

If you want to range over your array in the way you do in the example, one option would be to make it an array of pointers to structs (i.e. `[]*PFile`).  That way the assignment in the loop will just take a pointer to the struct allowing you to modify it.