# Looping over slice of aliased(user defined) types gives type before aliasing

Tags: go

I'm trying to loop over slice of user defined types (in example below these are aliased int), but range produces values of type int, instead of MyInt as I would expect. Casting inside 'if' helps for sure, but I would like to understand why range does not produces values of type MyInt.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyInt int

const (
    MYINT00 MyInt = iota
    MYINT01
)

func main() {
    var myInt02 MyInt = 2
    myInts := []MyInt{MYINT00, MYINT01}
    for i := range myInts {
        if i == myInt02 {
            fmt.Println("same")
        }
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/nb77pvTMdkW

Error:

```
prog.go:18:8: invalid operation: i == myInt02 (mismatched types int and MyInt)
```

Then I thought that problem can be related to consts and iota, so I used variables declared in function - didn't change anything.

https://play.golang.org/p/0fVRhBtvlOL
https://play.golang.org/p/pioDSU4oJdP

I haven't found any info in Effective Go/other questions. If anybody has some input on that, please share!

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range

Comment: Here is your cure for a broader understanding of the use-case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185511/golang-range-references-instead-values

Comment: This is **not** a type alias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [For statements with range clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> ```
> Range expression                          1st value          2nd value
>
> array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
> ```

---

`i` is the `range` index, an `int`, not the `range` value.

For example, fixing your code to use the `range` value,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyInt int

const (
    MYINT00 MyInt = iota
    MYINT01
)

func main() {
    var myInt02 MyInt = 2
    myInts := []MyInt{MYINT00, MYINT01}
    for _, v := range myInts {
        if v == myInt02 {
            fmt.Println("same")
        }
    }
}
```