# How can I append items to the map in range?

Tags: go

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/imdario/mergo"
)

func main() {
    var DATA []map[string]interface{}
    text := []byte(`[{"id":1,"test":1},{"id":2},{"id":3,"test":3},{"test":8}]`)
    err := json.Unmarshal(text, &DATA)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("ERR: %s", err)
    }

    var STATE map[string]interface{}
    var newState []interface{}

    fmt.Println("DATA: ", DATA)

    for _, k := range DATA {
        if err := mergo.Merge(&STATE, k, mergo.WithOverride); err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("Error merge new and old packets: %s", err)
        }
        fmt.Println("STATE: ", STATE)

        newState = append(newState, STATE)
    }

    fmt.Println(newState)

}
```

I get: **[map[id:3 test:8] map[test:8 id:3] map[id:3 test:8] map[test:8 id:3]]**
I want get **[map[id:1 test:1] map[test:2 id:1] map[id:3 test:3] map[test:8 id:3]]**

I can not understand why the last value falls into the data slice, and not what was at the time of writing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Range references instead values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185511/range-references-instead-values)

Comment: Maps are unordered. So there's no way to guarantee you'll get what you want.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. The expected output is exactly the same as the input, so why not just `fmt.Println(DATA)`?

Comment: @Peter I updated the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what the problem is, I need to explicitly copy each value

```
for key,value := range STATE {
    newState[i][key] = value
}
```