# range over addressess of struct array

Tags: go

I have a struct array of type []Struct. When I range over it in the form:

```
for i, val := range mystructarray
```

I understand that val is a local variable which contains a copy of mystructarray[i]. Is there a better way of iterating through the addressess of mystructarray than this:

```
for i := range mystructarray{
    valptr = &mystructarray[i]
}
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change values while iterating in golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945030/change-values-while-iterating-in-golang)

Comment: The answer to the questions may overlap, but that question is really asking about a different issue. Someone who comes to the site looking for an answer to my question won't necessarily find the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to iterate while receiving a pointer to the contents of the slice (unless of course, it is a slice of pointers).

Your example is the best way:

```
for i := range mySlice {
    x = &mySlice[i]
    // do something with x
}
```

Remember however, if your structs aren't very large, and you don't need to operate on them via a pointer, it may be faster to copy the struct, and provide you with clearer code.