# Golang edit array of struts from main() to function

Tags: pointers, struct, go

hoping you can help below is a concise version of my code.

basically im passing an array of structs to floatInSlice() in which either a new struct gets added to the array or an existing struct AudienceCategory.Sum gets ++

all is generally working fine except for the b.Sum = b.Sum+1

Now I know that if I want to pass an obect as a pointer rather than value I need to use */& but I just cant seem to get it working, any help much appriciated!

```
type AudienceCategory struct {
    Cat int
    Sum int
}


var counter = []AudienceCategory{}


func main() {
     for i := 1; i < len(words); i++ {
         counter = floatInSlice(category,counter)
        if counter != nil{}
     }
     fmt.Printf("%v ", counter) 
}


func floatInSlice(category int, counter *[]AudienceCategory) []AudienceCategory {
    for _, b := range counter {
        if b.Cat == category {
            b.Sum = b.Sum+1

            return counter
        }
    }
    x := AudienceCategory{Cat:category,Sum:1}
    counter = append( counter, x)
    return counter
}
```

EDIT ***********

got it working in the end thanks for the help guys

```
func floatInSlice(category int, counter []AudienceCategory) []AudienceCategory {

    for i := 0; i < len(counter); i++ {
        if counter[i].Cat == category {
            counter[i].Sum = counter[i].Sum+1

            return counter
        }
    }
    x := AudienceCategory{Cat:category,Sum:1}
    counter = append( counter, x)
    return counter
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945030/change-values-while-iterating-in-golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use value range as in `_, b := range counter`, `b` contains a copy of each element of `counter`. So you are summing a copy that is lost, not the element in the slice.

You should use

```
func floatInSlice(category int, counter *[]AudienceCategory) []AudienceCategory {
    for i, b := range *counter {
        if b.Cat == category {
            (*counter)[i].Sum = (*counter)[i].Sum+1

            return counter
        }
    }
    x := AudienceCategory{Cat:category,Sum:1}
    counter = append( counter, x)
    return counter
}
```

Comment: many thx siritinga but im getting the below errors.....

./readfile.go:83: cannot use counter (type []AudienceCategory) as type *[]AudienceCategory in argument to floatInSlice

./readfile.go:147: cannot range over counter (type *[]AudienceCategory)

./readfile.go:151: cannot use counter (type *[]AudienceCategory) as type []AudienceCategory in return argument

./readfile.go:155: first argument to append must be slice; have *[]AudienceCategory

./readfile.go:156: cannot use counter (type *[]AudienceCategory) as type []AudienceCategory in return argument

Comment: cannot range over counter (type *[]AudienceCategory)