# Reference type confusing in Go language

Tags: go, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, trie, pass-by-name

I tried to make Trie data structures by Go Language, but somehow it stuck with References problem, 
Here it is. http://play.golang.org/p/ASSGF5Oe9R

```
// Package main provides ...
package main

import "fmt"

type RootTrie []Trie

type Trie struct {
    subtrie []Trie
    index   byte
}

func (trie *Trie) Insert(data string) *Trie {
    if data != "" {
        if trie.index == 0 {
            trie.index = data[0]
        }
        if next := trie.containsIndex(data[1:]); next != nil {
            //Problem Point
            fmt.Println(string(data[1]), "found follwing", string(data[0]))
            next.Insert(data[1:])
        } else {
            nt := &Trie{}
            trie.subtrie = append(trie.subtrie, *nt.Insert(data[1:]))
        }
    }

    return trie
}
func (trie *Trie) containsIndex(next string) *Trie {
    if next != "" {
        for _, st := range trie.subtrie {
            if st.index == next[0] {
                return &st
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    t := &Trie{}
    t = t.Insert("hanyang")
    fmt.Println("result:", t)
    t = t.Insert("hanyKk")
    fmt.Println("result:", t)
    t.Insert("hanyK")
}
```

The following problems happen in second "Insert", 
the where I put, `//Problem Point`

I made `containsIndex` method for searching next linked trie, and it searched well actually. 
But when I updated `next` property which `containsIndex` given, its not affected its mother struct `trie` though.

What I don't understand is I gave it reference type when returning `containsIndex`, but its still
act liked 'value copied', Why does it not affected its mother structure(`trie`)?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get the -1--there're language nits, but it explains the nature of the problem and there's code you can mess around with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in method containsIndex. Golang `range` by default creates copy each element in slice and assigns copy of this value to `st` (in your example). Usually to preserve reference to element in slice you should use original slice and its index. In you case method containsIndex should look something like this:

```
func (trie *Trie) containsIndex(next string) *Trie {
    if next != "" {
        for i, st := range trie.subtrie {
            if st.index == next[0] {
                return &trie.subtrie[i]
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Does this also imply a performance difference when using just indices, instead of values as well?

Comment: @EtienneBruines -- Maybe. It might be it's negligible, or there might be no difference if the compiler recognizes it can optimize the copy away sometimes. If you run into this choice in a performance-critical inner loop, you can always test.

Comment: @twotwotwo Thank you for your response. I've ran some benchmarks: in non-complicated cases, there is no performance difference at all. https://github.com/EtienneBruines/go-range-performance-analysis

Comment: Thanks, @wonsky. and I found some interesting answers there I examine about address differences  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15952415/369929)