# Modify array of interface{} golang

Tags: go

This type assertion, def-referencing has been driving me crazy.  So I have a nested structure of `Key string / Value interface{}` pairs.  Stored in the `Value` is an `[]interface` which I want to modify each of the values.  Below is an example of creating an array of `Bar` and passing it into the `ModifyAndPrint` function which should modify the top level structure.  The problem that I come accross is as written it doesn't actually modify the contents of z, and I can't do a `q := z.([]interface{})[i].(Bar)` or `&` thereof.

Is there a way to do this? If so, what combination did I miss?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Bar struct {
   Name string
   Value int
}

func ModifyAndPrint(z interface{}){
    fmt.Printf("z before: %v\n", z)
    for i, _ := range(z.([]interface{})) {      
        q := z.([]interface{})[i]
        b := (q).(Bar)
        b.Value = 42
        fmt.Printf("Changed to: %v\n", b)
    }
    fmt.Printf("z after: %v\n", z)
}

func main() {       
    bars := make([]interface{}, 2)
    bars[0] = Bar{"a",1}
    bars[1] = Bar{"b",2}

    ModifyAndPrint(bars)    
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/vh4QXS51tq

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945030/change-values-while-iterating-in-golang

Comment: I'm confused by that link.  It seems like it says to use indexing, which I am doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program is modifying a copy of the value in the interface{}. One way to achieve your goal is to assign the modified value back to the slice:

```
for i, _ := range(z.([]interface{})) {      
    q := z.([]interface{})[i]
    b := (q).(Bar)
    b.Value = 42
    z.([]interface{})[i] = b
    fmt.Printf("Changed to: %v\n", b)
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/XFDV4wxyj4)

Comment: That works, but is there a better way that doesn't involve creating a modified element and assigning back?  Can I just work with the original value?