# Modifying a struct slice within a struct in Go

Tags: pointers, go, struct, slice

In the following example, a `person` has a slice of `friendship`s, and I try to initialize a `friendship` as a pointer to another `person` object, but for some reason it fails, and the result is that nobody has any `friendship`s. Am I not using a pointer somewhere where I should be?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

type friendship struct {
    friend *person
}

type person struct {
    name       int
    friendship []friendship
}

func createPerson(id int) person {
    return person{id, make([]friendship, 0)}
}

func (p *person) addFriends(possibleFriends []*person, numFriends int) {
    var friend *person
    for i := 0; i < numFriends; i++ {
        friend = possibleFriends[rand.Intn(len(possibleFriends))]
        p.friendship = append(p.friendship, friendship{friend})
    }
}

func main() {
    numPeople := 20
    people := make([]person, numPeople)
    possibleFriends := make([]*person, numPeople)
    for i := 0; i < numPeople; i++ {
        people[i] = createPerson(i)
        possibleFriends[i] = &(people[i])
    }
    for _, p := range people {
        p.addFriends(possibleFriends, 2)
    }
    fmt.Println(people)
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945030/change-values-while-iterating-in-golang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
for i := 0; i < numPeople; i++ {
        people[i].addFriends(possibleFriends, 2)
}
```

or

```
 for i, _ := range people {
        people[i].addFriends(possibleFriends, 2)
 }
```

instead of

```
 for _, p := range people {
        p.addFriends(possibleFriends, 2)
 }
```

this is because `p` is a copy of `people[i]`, `addFriends` has no effect on slice `people`

Comment: better yet, we can do  
`for i := range people {
        people[i].addFriends(possibleFriends, 2)
 }`