# A little bit confuse about the iteration values of golang for loop

Tags: pointers, for-loop, go

This question is relate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945030/change-values-while-iterating-in-golang) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952415/5938111)

All of these question & answer all make sense to me except one little thing.

If the 2nd value of for loop is a[i], then what is the different between the `a[i]` from the for loop and the `a[i]` as we write? It looks like the same thing but it isn't, right?

Please help me clear this out. Thanks guys!

Comment: If you use the value from range it is a copy at a different memory location. If you use a[idx] you are editing the memory in the slice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
a := make([]int, 3)

a[0], a[1], a[2] = 1, 2, 3

for i, val := range a {
    println(a[i], "vs.", val)
    println(&a[i], "vs.", &val)
}
```

The variable `val` is assigned **a copy** of the value in `a[i]`.

It is basically the same as doing it like this:

```
var val int
for i := range a {
    val = a[i]
    println(a[i], "vs.", val)
    println(&a[i], "vs.", &val)
}
```

So depending on what you are doing then:

> It looks like the same thing but it isn't, right?

If you use the variable to read the value, then *it is* the same thing.

But if you assign to it, take it's pointer value, etc, *it is not*.